# Youtube API - Send MCN Network Join Invitation

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to know if it was possible to send an invitation to join an MCN through the API instead of through the YouTube site directly.
All I seem to need is the Channel ID in order to do it through the site so is there an area of the API that I can submit a Channel ID and the request will then be sent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.